# Generate reformatted text list

Tags: javascript, text, logic

I'm trying to find a way using Javascript (or really anything else that works, but I'm used to Javascript) to take a formatted list of names as such:

```
[[Equipment Bugs]]
[[Item Duplication Glitch]]
```

to

```
[[Equipment Bugs]]
[[equipment bugs]]
[[Item Duplication Glitch]]
[[item duplication glitch]]
```

So basically taking one line and duplicating it in place, but taking this duplicate and lowercasing it.

Looks like a homework question, but I actually need this in order to batch rename articles on a mediawiki project via a bot.

Things I've tried so far:

I have tried taking my list as a string and then `str.toLowerCase()` but obviously, this just gives me a lowercased list, when I need the original name and then the lowercase output below that. I don't even know where to start when it comes to the logic of it, much less the programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you need to split the input into lines, then loop through each line to show the original case, then the lower case.

```
var original = "[[Equipment Bugs]]\n[[Item Duplication Glitch]]";
var lines = original.split("\n");
var result = "";
for (var line in lines) {
  result += lines[line] + "\n" //The original case
          + lines[line].toLowerCase() + "\n"; //The lower case
}
console.log(result);
```